# Web API calls are slow in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, webapi

I'm developing a web API and I hosted it on Azure, I have a call that takes about 2.5 seconds in my local machine but takes a lot longer when the app is hosted in Azure as you can see in this figure:

[image]

It's taking 12.8 seconds which is not expected, why is this happening, and what is the part highlighted in red? Why does it take about 10 seconds to start with the first operation in the code? I have "AlwaysOn " on ON so this is not my API going to sleep, also, sometimes the call takes less time (4-6 seconds) which an inconsistency, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

If, CPU usage is not high, one reason could be SNAT port exhaustion / pending, if you have too many open TCP connections (including SQL Server's) then new connection will wait.
You can check that from your app service "Diagnose and solve problems" -> "Availability and Performance" -> "SNAT Port Exhaustion".
[image]

If this is the case, this is a good place to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to increase the tier of your app service plan? This will help you to understand if it's an infrastructure or code problem